# XMLHttpRequest cannot retrieve the json output

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

My goal is to get the json output of a Http "Get". Then use this json output into D3.

I created a httpGet function like follows, the settings are exact the same as my Postman, and I can get the json response in Postman.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true, "admin", "admin" );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-M2M-Origin', '//localhost:10000');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-M2M-RI', '12345');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-M2M-OT', 'NOW');
    xmlHttp.send();
    return "[" + xmlHttp.responseText + "]";
}



 var aaa = httpGet('localhost:8282/InCSE1/?rcn=4');
```

They are in the same domain. In javascript, chrome tells me that:

> OPTIONS /localhost:8282/InCSE1/?rcn=4 httpGet @ (index):118update @
>   (index):105(anonymous function) @ (index):61t @
>   d3.v3.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1t @ d3.v3.min.js:1u
>   @ d3.v3.min.js:1 (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8282/InCSE1/?rcn=4. Invalid HTTP status code 500!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWF4S.png

Answer (score 0):

**status code 500!**

This means its a server error not a client side issue.